# C++ std::thread synchronization inside loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, synchronization

I made a mistake by choosing std::thread to make my thread concurrency assignment. I have no time left to learn some other method. So I hope you can help me out here, I'm really confused about all those types of mutexes, promises, futures etc. The lack of diverse documentation/tutorials is depressing.
So I want 3 threads (players) to do the same thing - pick 2 random numbers as indexes for a global 2-D array, if the value of the cell is 0 set it equal to the thread's Id, otherwise stop execution of the thread. Do this in a loop until there's only one thread left.
What I need is to find a way to synchronize the 3 threads after every (before the next) iteration so that one thread couldn't be on the 50th iteration, while the other is on, say, 30th, i.e., thread has to wait for all the others to complete the iteration before moving on.  I need some kind of barrier.
I tried using condition variables to put the threads to sleep until the last finishing thread signals to wake them up but I couldn't get it working.
My unsuccessful tries are commented out:

```
std::mutex GridMutex, FinishMutex, LeftMutex;
int Grid[X][Y], Finished = 0, PlayersLeft = 3;

void Fight(int Id) {
  int RandX, RandY, i = 0;
  std::random_device rd; // access random device
  std::mt19937 e(rd()); // seed the engine
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> r1(0, X-1);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> r2(0, Y-1);
  LeftMutex.lock(); // mutex on PlayersLeft
  while (PlayersLeft != 1) {
    ++i;
    /*std::call_once(flag, [Id, i](){*/std::cout << " Round " << i << "  Left: " << PlayersLeft << '\n';/*});*/
    LeftMutex.unlock();
//     FinishMutex.lock();
//     std::call_once(flag, [](){Finished = 0;});
//     FinishMutex.unlock();
    RandX = r1(e);
    RandY = r2(e);
    GridMutex.lock();
    if (Grid[RandX][RandY] != Id) {
      if (Grid[RandX][RandY] == 0) {
        Grid[RandX][RandY] = Id;
        std::cout << "i= "<< i << " Thread " << Id << " occupied cell " << RandX << RandY << '\n';
        std::chrono::milliseconds sleepDuration(100);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(sleepDuration); //just to lock the grid for some time
        GridMutex.unlock();
      }
      else {
        GridMutex.unlock();
        LeftMutex.lock();
        --PlayersLeft;
        LeftMutex.unlock();
        break; //stop thread if cell occupied
      }
    }
    //Wait for the others here
//     FinishMutex.lock();
//     ++Finished;
//     if (Finished == 3) {
//       FinishMutex.unlock();
//       AllReady.notify_all();
//     }
//     else {
//       FinishMutex.unlock();
//       AllReady.wait(Lk, [](){return Finished == 3;});
//       Lk.unlock();
//     }
    LeftMutex.lock();
  }
}
int main() {
  SetGrid();
  std::thread t1(&Fight, 1);
  std::thread t2(&Fight, 2);
  std::thread t3(&Fight, 3);
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  t3.join();
  GetGrid();
  return 0;
}
```

I expected the expressions inside the "call_once" thing to be executed by only one thread (whichever comes first) on every iteration but obiviously it's not what I thought it was because that results in some strange behaviour. How to do that?
Ok, the code may be ugly and all that should be put inside classes and methods or something , but I just need to get this working no matter how primitively.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: So if I get this right, you want 3 threads to random select a element of an array, if it is non zero the threads ends, else it tries again and you want all of the threads in sync until there is one left?

Comment: You didn't make a mistake in using `std::thread`. You made a mistake in not understanding basic multithreading.

Comment: Yes, but also if its nonzero but equal to Id then do nothing, skip to the next iteration.

Comment: Why don't you try "Cyclic Barrier" synchronization primitive for such a cyclic task senario? It's easy to implement with std::mutex, std::condition_variable using examples from Boost.Thread http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/boost/thread/barrier.hpp
See also: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html (Java API)

Answer (score 1):

You could remove some locks by using [atomic variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) like `std::atomic_int` and `std::atomic_bool` (or `std::atomic_flag`.

Next to that, don't do the locking and unlocking yourself but use `RAII` wrappers for this, like [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard). This will lock the specified mutex until the lock object itself is destroyed (usually when it goes out of scope).

Now, while using those things will improve your code vastly, your actual logical error is quite simple: you should not compare to the constant 3 but to `playersLeft`. Note that as the condition is dependant on this you also have to signal whenever you change this variable.

Comment: I could remove LeftMutex and FinishMutex? And not GridMutex? So I change int PlayerLeft, Finished with std::atomic<int>. But to compare, change or to get their values, do I have to use store, load and compare_exchange functions? I guess not. Can I place lock_guard before the first "if" statement and remove GridMutex? Would it unlock itself after the whole "if" block? Yes, I was aware of that playersLeft error, just forgot to correct it.

Comment: What about that call_once thing? Thank you, You help me a lot!

Comment: @user1079355: You can use most numerical atomic types just like the integers itself, almost all operators like assignment, `+`, `++`, ... are overloaded for this purpose. A scoped lock will be removed after it goes out of scope, so if you place it before the if it will only get released on the end of the wile. If you want one for the if (including the if-statement itself), you just introduce a new scope with `{}`. The advantage with scope-based guards is it cleans up your mess if you do things like `throw, break, return`.

Comment: `call_once` does what it exactly says it does, call something once. If you want one call per iterator for all threads, you need something else (e.g. set a flag `controler` to `true` for only one thread, and only print on that flag).

Comment: Also, fyi, I got your code to work without any deadlocks with 2 `mutex` (though I think I could get rid of one without much pain), 1 `atomic_int` and 1 `condition_variable` and a few `guard_lock`/`unique_locks`. Just as a hint, you're missing a notify_all in the code posted above (imagine: what if a thread terminates?)

Comment: Ok, I will try this tomorrow. I don't really know how to implement that second notify. Same AllReady.notify_all(); before "break;"? Doesn't look good - I started to get "what():  Operation not permitted" error after replacing int Finished with atomic.

Comment: Man, I feel bad you giving me so many tips and I'm not getting anywhere :D Here is where I'm at: [code](http://pastebin.com/A1MHU47E). I have commented out everything nonessential but still can't find the error. There must be something wrong with that unique lock inside the wait() function and/or the Finished variable. The program freezes after one of the threads blocks (wait()) in the second round. Why should the wait() function lock an atomic integer? I also tried the code using Finished as a normal int and with mutexes but that resulted in deadlock even before any output.

Comment: Can you just please show me how you got it working? I'm really running out of time, and my flags or something are just not working.

Comment: Sorry, I do not provide explicit answers if it is clearly a homework question. A hint: think about what will happen if the while-condition is no longer fulfilled.